# Wordpress multiply meta_query and one metakey could not exist

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem. I have two metakeys `price` and `new-price`, `new-price` doesn't fill in every post. And when I'm doing such search it works for posts with both filled metakeys, but if `new-price` didn't fill it didn't.

For example, two products **"Banana price=5, new-price=3" and "Apple price=5"**. `$startPrice=0` and `$endPrice=3`. It will show me both banana and apple, but I need only "Banana", because `new-price` fits into `$startPrice` and `$endPrice`. This bug comes because "Apple" haven't filled metakey 'new-price'. How to solve it?

```
$clothes = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'clothes',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'key' => 'new-price',
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'value' => array($startPrice,$endPrice),
        'compare' => 'between'
      ),
      array(

        'key' => 'price',
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'value' => array($startPrice,$endPrice),
        'compare' => 'between'
      )
    )
  )));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another query to check if your `new-price` is empty or not.

try this

```
$clothes = get_posts(
array(
    'post_type' => 'clothes',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'new-price',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'new-price',
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'value' => array($startPrice, $endPrice),
                'compare' => 'between'
            ),
            array(

                'key' => 'price',
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'value' => array($startPrice, $endPrice),
                'compare' => 'between'
            )
        ),
    ),
)
);
```

this might work for you. look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for reference on using meta query

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work correctly. Now "Apple" doesn't even show, if $startPrice = 0, $endPrice = 5.

Answer (score 0):

Solved like this

```
$footwear = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'products_footwear',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'main-razdel',
      'value' => $categoryID,
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'key' => 'new-price',
          'value' => '',
          'compare' => '!=',
          'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
          'key' => 'new-price',
          'type' => 'numeric',
          'value' => array($startPrice,$endPrice),
          'compare' => 'between'
        )
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'value' => array($startPrice,$endPrice),
        'compare' => 'between'
      )
    )
  )));
```